# How to remove square brackets and commas from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a tooltip for Likes. Here's an `images` which I'm passing to tooltip:

```
images = bonus.like_user_avatars.map {|src| "<img src='#{src}'>" }
```

`bonus.like_user_avatar` is already a collection of the liked user's avatar.
Everything works fine, but it looks like this:

[image]

This is the tooltip code:

```
span.has-tip data-tooltip="" data-template="<div class='tooltip'>#{images}</div>"Like
```

I need to remove the square brackets and commas, I just want only the avatars in tooltip. How can I do it?

Comment: can you please show full partial or view

Comment: @Deepak see upd

Comment: It's not necessary, or particularly desirable, that you use "edit" or "updated" tags in the text. Instead, simply incorporate the change as if it'd been there all along, so it makes sense and is readable. We can look at the revision history if we need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `join` the values in array

```
images.join # <img src='a.jpg'><img src='b.jpg'><img src='c.jpg'>
```

Just replace the code with following:

```
span.has-tip data-tooltip="" data-template="<div class='tooltip'>#{images.join}</div>"Like
```

Comment: You were passing the array as it is

Comment: that's why the comma , quotes and brackets after `join` it will remove those things

Answer (score 1):

Two possiblities:

1. You probably need to tell rails that your HTML is safe. Call
   `.html_safe` on the string when you render it.
2. I would rather save of the `src` attributes in the `bonus.like_user_avatars` as you've done, and then add them into the html upon render through a rails method. For example in your view (assuming you're using slim from your previous syntax).

   ```
   - bonus.like_user_avatars.each do |src|
     = image_tag src, #any options you want here
   ```

**Note**: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag will help with the `image_tag` method

Comment: Ah with context mine is not as relevant. @Deepak That's a great way :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between `map` and `each`.

```
2.3.0 :001 > array = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3]
2.3.0 :002 > array.map {|v| v+1}
 => [2, 3, 4]
2.3.0 :003 > array.each {|v| v+1}
 => [1, 2, 3]
```

`map` is used when you want to transform the original list (it does not mutate). When you use `map`, you are just creating a new list with the new values. `each` should be used when you want to have some kind of effect, in this case, you are outputting something.

In your case, you will want to use `bonus.like_user_avatars.each`